# Copy mysql schema from a remote server to local with mysqldump

Tags: mysql

I want to copy the database schema from a remote server with mysqldump. The local database get the schema, but also, I get an error from console.

```
mysqldump -h200.200.200.200 --no-data --no-create-db --single-transaction --routines -u root -psecretpass remote_db | mysql -u root -psecretpass local_db
```

What this's mean? Should I worry about?

```
ERROR 1 (HY000) at line 4158: Can't create/write to file './remote_db/db.opt' (Errcode: 2 - No such file or directory)
```

Comment: Are the two servers running the same MySQL version? My guess is that the remote server is running a newer version, and it's putting something into the dump file that the local server doesn't understand.

Comment: The mysql version on remote is older.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you have `create procedure` permissions:

--routines

Use of this option requires the SELECT privilege for the mysql.proc table. So you might get the table schema, but nor procedures and functions

Comment: The SELECT privilege on remote server or local?

Comment: Privileges are always *local* to the database you are querying against. SO in this case you need it for the receiving (local)